# DevOps Release pipeline is creating a release after a PR build

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

There's a [Build Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#build-validation) step for a PR, so a build is created each time a PR is created.

I only want a release to be created once a PR has been approved and completed not when a PR has been created.

As you can see from this screenshot.
[image]

`Release 12` was created when a PR was approved and completed.

However, `release 13` was created when the build associated with a PR creation succeeded.  Don't want these.

These are my settings in the Release pipeline `Continuous Deployment Trigger`

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: "Once a PR has been approved and merged" == "when a commit to the protected branch". So you don't want the build to be a part of the PR at all, you just need to set your CI triggers appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PR release workflow is based on:

- a PR build, a pre-merged build with master
- the release of this PR build

If don't want every build to be released you can set the queue to Manual in: Settings > Repositories > Build policy
[image: Settings > Repositories]

But what you can't accomplish in this workflow, is that "once a PR has been approved and completed " a release is made.

The PR release is an important step, which even can even be required, in the PR workflow, before it gets completed.
You will also find this in Settings > Repositories > Build policy:
[image: Settings > Repositories]

What could help is filtering out only specific builds with tags:
[image]

More information on the PR release workflow, with classic pipelines check:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#pull-request-triggers

But if your after only releasing `release12` in your example, don't use the PR trigger and just start your release based on the CD trigger with a proper filter:

[image: CD trigger]